# Nagios Core4.4.3 snmptrap

Tags: linux, nagios

I followed the instructions at the link:
 [Snmptrap-config-ling](https://kb.netapp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1030102/~/how-to%3A-configuring-nagios-to-receive-solidfire-snmp-traps-)
To configure Nagios Core 4.4.3 with snmptrap for a Sonicwall, and a Netapp, it works perfectly but I have a problem / error with:
When I receive a snmptrap it looks like this:

[Image with snmptrap issue receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIWCn.png)

Which I say is good.
 But unfortunately when the port / alarm returns (reset):

[Image with resolvet snmptrap issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnQeD.png)

Can't make it to turn and reset itself to green automatically (i must reset it manually to green with a schedulded check), or is it normal to be like that?
Can you help me please with a tip?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that what happens is that the SNMP trap technically sends what's called a "passive" check result to the service you have defined. This will cause the service to switch state. If your hardware is not configured in such a way that it will send a new trap when the issue is cleared, you will have to handle a reset to the OK state on your own.

Passive checks have a "freshness" value which basically means that if no new passive results have come in for a certain amount of time, an active check should be run instead. If you wish to automatically clear these, one way could be to have this active check automatically return OK, resetting the service. A more intelligent way would be to somehow *verify* that the problem is resolved (in the script) before resetting the state. Of course, if you just throw an OK without any checks, you may miss the warning unless you have good visibility of your incoming alarms.

Doing it manually may be better as you probably want the service to be in a failed state until you know you have fixed the issue. It's up to you.